# Calculation of $\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)\mu(\frac nd)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I see in literature on elementary number theory all kinds of Dirichlet convolutions calculated for well-known functions like Euler $\phi$ and Moebius $\mu$. But I didnt meet the calculation of $$\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)\mu(\frac nd)$$ yet. Does it make sense to calculate this and how can it be done ?

Comment: Hint: Use multiplicativity. The calculation for prime powers is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Convolution of multiplicative arithmetic functions is also multiplicative, so we need only compute it for $n=p^r$. ($p$ is prime and $r\ge1$ is integer).

$$\sum_{d\mid p^r}\phi(d)\mu\left(\frac{p^r}d\right)=\sum_{s=0}^r\phi(p^s)\mu(p^{r-s})=\phi(p^r)-\phi(p^{r-1})$$
since $\mu(p^k)=0$ for $k\ge 2$.

Can you finish?

Comment: Hm. I calculated thus: $f(p^r)=\sum_{d\mid p^r}\phi(d)\mu\left(\frac{p^r}d\right)=p^{k-1}(p-1)-p^{k-2}(p-1)=p^{k-2}(p-1)^2$ This is now ( but dont know whether this is allowed ) $$f(p^r)=p^{k-1}(p-1)(1-\frac 1p)=\phi(p^k)(1-\frac 1p)$$ or $$f(p^r)=p^r(1-\frac 1p)^2$$ Now for general $n$ ?

Comment: Is this true ? $$f(n)=\frac{\phi(n)^2}{n}$$ Must still do some CAS checking as I cant believe that $n$ is a divisor of $\phi(n)^2$.

Comment: The above formula seems to break down if at least one prime divisor of $n$ is squarefree.